# Download artifacts from JFrog with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, cicd, jfrog-pipelines

I wrote a Jenkins pipeline to download the artifcats from JFrog. I have artifactory plugin for Jenkins so I use **rtdownload**. Below is the rtdownload section

```
rtDownload (
              serverId: 'pe-jfrog',
                            spec: '''{
                                "files": [
                                    {
                                    "pattern": "my-local-repo-dev/test-${buildVersion}.tar"

                                    }
                                ]
                            }''',

                            buildName: 'my-test-build',
                            buildNumber: "${env.buildVersion}"
                        )
```

I use choice parameter to get buildversion. With this I'm able to download.

Now my requirement is how can I pass the value to **pattern**

I decalred variable as `def jfrogrepo = "my-local-repo/test-${buildVersion}.tar"`

I tried to call this variable as

- "pattern" : "${jfrogrepo}"
- "pattern" : jfrogrepo

None of it works.But on echoing the variable I'm getting correct output.

So is there a way to pass variable to pattern or is there any other way to download the artifacts by making use of the artifacory plugin.

Comment: Have you tried `"""` instead of `'''` for spec parameter? Variables inside single quotes aren't substituted.

Comment: Have you tried "$env.jfrogrepo"

Answer (score 0):

```
rtDownload (
  serverId: 'pe-jfrog',
  spec: """{
    "files": [
      {
        "pattern": "my-local-repo-dev/test-${env.buildVersion}.tar"
      }
    ]
  }""",
  buildName: 'my-test-build',
  buildNumber: "${env.buildVersion}"
)
```

there is difference in groovy for single/double quotes

i like this page

https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4

in quick

in single quotes variables will not be interpolated/evaluated. ${} this will not work

in double quotes vars ${} evaluated to actual value

FYI

`env.` its global variable for jenkins pipeline treated as environment variable in sh script and global variable for jenkinsfile part of currentbuild object

parameters in pipeline used as `${params.VARIABLE}` see [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the CLI of JFrog for Jenkins? you can use [Jfrog plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jfrog/) for your purpose and after that you can add JFrog CLI as tools in JFrog artifactory, then you can use this command in Jenkinsfile and pipeline:

```
jf "rt dl my-local-repo/cool-froggy.zip"
```